# Indexing by float or double field algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I have a task to perform fast search in huge in-memory array of objects by some object's fields. I need to select the subset of objects satisfying some criteria.

The criteria may be specified as a floating point value or range of such values (eg. `2.5..10`).

The problem is that the float property to be searched on is not quite uniformly distributed; it could contain few objects with value range `10-20` (for example) and another million objects with values `0-1`, and another million with values `100-150`.

So, how possible is it to build index for effective searching those objects? Code samples are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fail to see what the distribution of values has to do with building an index (with the possible exception of exact duplicates).  Since the data fits in memory, just extract all the fields with their original position, sort them, and use a binary search as suggested by @MattiLyra.

Are we missing something?

Comment: Depending on latency requirements, distribution could be relevant for shaping access locality.

Answer (score 2):

If the in memory array is ordered then binary search would be my first attempt. Wikipedia entry has example code as well.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing lookups only, a single sort followed by multiple binary searches is good.

You could also try a perfect hash algorithm, if you want the ultimate in lookup speed and little more.

If you need more than just lookups, check out treaps and red-black trees.  The former are fast on average, while the latter are decent performers with a low operation duration variability.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a [range tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree), for the range requirement.